# Building AOSP ROM with CM device tree and vendor tree?

Tags: android-source

So I have downloaded the master AOSP i.e Lollipop. I want to build it for Xiaomi Redmi 1s. The device specific sources are available on github on this link: https://github.com/armani-dev
So what modifications I have to make to successfully build the ROM.

Comment: Did you have any luck ? Can you post what you did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use other **AOSP** device trees as reference.
- Change any mentions of **CM** to **AOSP**.

You'll probably have issues with the overlay folder, so I'd say you're best off deleting it for now.

And just saying, if you don't have any experience with porting custom ROMs and modifying makefiles, then you'll have big trouble getting AOSP Lollipop up and running.

You're better off waiting a month or so until Cyanogenmod Lollipop code is stable enough to be built. You'll have a much easier time building.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for learning to edit the make files in the sources